# Trouble getting a derived QWidget to paint itself

Tags: qt4, repaint

I have made my own simple widget by deriving from QWidget, and am trying to get it to paint a gradient inside its paintEvent(). I set a breakpoint inside paintEvent, but it never gets called, even when I resize the window etc. The widget is a promoted QWidget from within the designer.
Here is my object code - I am not actually reading the gradient colors yet, just trying to get the paintEvent() to fire first hehe.
First, the header file:

```
#ifndef GRADIENT_H
#define GRADIENT_H

#include <QBrush>
#include <QPen>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QWidget>


class Gradient : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Gradient(QWidget *parent = 0);

    QSize minimumSizeHint() const;
    QSize sizeHint() const;

public slots:

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);

private:

};

#endif // GRADIENT_H
```

Then, the .cpp:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QPen>

#include "gradient.h"


Gradient::Gradient(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{

   //setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Base);
    //setAutoFillBackground(true);
}

QSize Gradient::minimumSizeHint() const
{
    return QSize(20, 256);
}

QSize Gradient::sizeHint() const
{
    return QSize(20, 512);
}

void Gradient::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * /* event */)
{
    //update();
    repaint();
}

void Gradient::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * /* event */)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.fillRect(rect(), Qt::black);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::blue,1));
   // painter.setBrush(?);

    for (int y = 0; y < height(); ++y)
    {
        painter.save();
      //painter.setPen(); <---here I plan to set different colors from a dynamic table
        painter.translate(0, y);

        painter.drawLine(0, 0, width(), 0);

        painter.restore();
    }
    painter.drawRect(QRect(0, 0, width() - 1, height() - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to call `update()` or `repaint()` inside the `resizeEvent()`. But that shouldn't break anything either. There must be something wrong with the promoted stuff because that `paintEvent()` override is correct. I pasted it into a QWidget subclass on my end and it works. Perhaps a clean all and rebuild?

Comment: Hmmm, do widgets get an initial paintEvent() when they are created/the app is loaded/main window shown? If not, I may need to find another way to do this. Thanks for testing the code out :)

Comment: OK, I rechecked evrything, and it looks like I never got the events because in between edits, the QTCreator app lost the widget "promotion" to my derived type. Going to mark you as the answer, thanks!